# Receiving Case Sensitive error's when Reading file using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def getcrc(lookfor,path):
    abspath = basepath+path
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(abspath):
        if lookfor in files:
            #print "Found: %s" % join(root, lookfor)         
            filename = join(root,lookfor)
            m = hashlib.md5()
        for line in open(filename,'rb'):
            m.update(line)
            print "File",filename,"CRC is ",m.hexdigest()
            return m.hexdigest()
```

I have made the above script to get the crc of a file, It works fine when the file name matches completely but I am not able to open that file when the Case sensitivity is violated, the file name is correct but i want to make this code case insensitive.

Below is the error I received :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\darshanb\temp\de.ecw.python.QCsnapshot\src\XmlReaderTesting.py", line 80, in <module>
    s3 = getcrc(filename,path)
  File "C:\Users\darshanb\temp\de.ecw.python.QCsnapshot\src\Testing.py", line 51, in getcrc
    for line in open(filename,'rb'):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment
```

For E.g. I have a filename in the XML as 'Appointments_ecw_resource.xsl' for which i want to find the CRC but in the actual server the name is lower 'appointments_ecw_resource.xsl' sometimes it is upper case do,
Is there a way that I can ignore the case sensitivity check.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `filename` variable is defined in an inner scope of preceding `if` statement. Initialize it outside of this scope or move your `for` loop inside (depending on the purpose).

Comment: This is the correct answer.  His `for` loop was over an empty list, meaning the body of the loop never executed and the variable hasn't been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You can match a file case insensitively by using `any()` and a generator expression:

```
lookfor = lookfor.lower()
if any(lookfor == fname.lower() for fname in files):
```

However, you still need to indent the `for` loop to fall within the `if` statement, because if your looked-for filename is *not* there, you still need to not read the file:

```
lookfor = lookfor.lower()
if any(lookfor == fname.lower() for fname in files):
    #print "Found: %s" % join(root, lookfor)         
    filename = join(root,lookfor)
    m = hashlib.md5()
    for line in open(filename,'rb'):
        m.update(line)
    print "File",filename,"CRC is ",m.hexdigest()
    return m.hexdigest()
```

Comment: I believe fname.lower should probably be fname.lower().  Also, wouldn't it be better to use a temporary variable for lookfor.lower(), rather than downcasing it once for every file in files?

Comment: @dstromberg: oops, corrected. Yes, a temporary would be better.